# Magento 2 cannot save category description - modsecurity SQL injection rule

Tags: magento, sql-injection, magento2, mod-security, mod-security2

I am working on a Magento 2 project and have been having trouble saving category descriptions.

In the Catalog Save controller action (***Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save***), I was logging the request parameters:

> $this->getRequest()->getParams()

On most categories all of the request parameters would come through, but certain ones would completely ignore the *POST* parameters.

After playing around with the description value being posted, I noticed that the request would not come through when my text had an instance of the text ***select*** followed later by an instance of ***from***.

My text was something like the following:

> *"We carry a **select**ion of knives **from** satin to mirror finish"*

I checked the modsecurity logs. It had filtering the requests, mistaking them as SQL injections.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the issue, we add configuration to remove the ModSecurity rules for our specific domains with:

```
<LocationMatch .*>
    SecRuleRemoveById 950004
</LocationMatch>
```

More on [removing ModSecurity rules](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/modsecurity/find-and-disable-specific-modsecurity-rules):

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/modsecurity/find-and-disable-specific-modsecurity-rules